# Why is my program crashing before the end of the loop?

Tags: vb.net

So the problem i am having is that my program seems to be crashing/not responding after the second last increment in the loop i have. My program is to ask the user the amount of students in the class, the max score on the test and then loop through the amount of students and the user gives the program the student name and their test score and then does other calculations within it.
The details of the score (name, marks, etc) are updated on a multi column list view at the end of each loop. The program works fine in the first increment of the loop but fails after that. Here's the code for the sub that does it:

```
Private Sub btnData_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnData.Click

    Dim NumStudent, HighestMark, LowestMark, ClassTotal, ClassMean, count As Integer
    Dim HscScore As Decimal

    Dim HscBand(5) As Integer
    Dim Band1 As Integer = HscBand(0)
    Dim Band2 As Integer = HscBand(1)
    Dim Band3 As Integer = HscBand(2)
    Dim Band4 As Integer = HscBand(3)
    Dim Band5 As Integer = HscBand(4)
    Dim Band6 As Integer = HscBand(5)

    NumStudent = InputBox("Enter the number of students for this test")
    NumStudent = NumStudent - 1

    MaxScore = InputBox("Enter the maximum score for this test")


    Dim student(NumStudent) As StudentHSC



    For count = 0 To NumStudent
        student(count).StudentName = InputBox("Enter the student's name")

        student(count).StudentScore = InputBox("Enter the student's score for the test")
        If student(count).StudentScore > MaxScore Then
            MessageBox.Show("You can not enter a number higher than the max score, please enter it again")
            student(count).StudentScore = InputBox("Enter the student's score for the test")
        End If

        HscScore = student(count).StudentScore / MaxScore * 100
        student(count).HscMark = Format(HscScore, "0.00")

        If student(count).HscMark < 50 Then
            student(count).HscRank = 1
            HscBand(0) = HscBand(0) + 1
            lstStuData.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {student(count).StudentName, student(count).StudentScore, student(count).HscMark, student(count).HscRank}))

        ElseIf student(count).HscMark = 50 And student(count).HscMark < 60 Then
            student(count).HscRank = 2
            HscBand(1) = HscBand(1) + 1
            lstStuData.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {student(count).StudentName, student(count).StudentScore, student(count).HscMark, student(count).HscRank}))

        ElseIf student(count).HscMark = 60 And student(count).HscMark < 70 Then
            student(count).HscRank = 3
            HscBand(2) = HscBand(2) + 1
            lstStuData.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {student(count).StudentName, student(count).StudentScore, student(count).HscMark, student(count).HscRank}))

        ElseIf student(count).HscMark = 70 And student(count).HscMark < 80 Then
            student(count).HscRank = 4
            HscBand(3) = HscBand(3) + 1
            lstStuData.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {student(count).StudentName, student(count).StudentScore, student(count).HscMark, student(count).HscRank}))

        ElseIf student(count).HscMark = 80 And student(count).HscMark < 90 Then
            student(count).HscRank = 5
            HscBand(4) = HscBand(4) + 1
            lstStuData.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {student(count).StudentName, student(count).StudentScore, student(count).HscMark, student(count).HscRank}))

        ElseIf student(count).HscMark = 90 And student(count).HscMark < 101 Then
            student(count).HscRank = 6
            HscBand(5) = HscBand(5) + 1
            lstStuData.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {student(count).StudentName, student(count).StudentScore, student(count).HscMark, student(count).HscRank}))

        End If







    Next
```

I've already had too many problems with this program, all have been solved except for this one. I have a feeling that it has something to do with NumStudent variable...

Also StudentHSC is a public function.

Edit: Here's the public variables and structure that i have set and the listview format:

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    lstStuData.View = View.Details
    lstStuData.Columns.Add("Student Name", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    lstStuData.Columns.Add("Score", 60, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    lstStuData.Columns.Add("Percentage", 70, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    lstStuData.Columns.Add("Band", 60, HorizontalAlignment.Left)


End Sub

Public MaxScore As Integer
Public student As String

Public Structure StudentHSC
    Dim StudentName As String
    Dim StudentScore As Integer
    Dim HscRank As Integer
    Dim HscMark As Integer
End Structure
```

Comment: Not sure as he is using the index from `0`.

Comment: What error do you get and on what line?

Comment: Debug your code by placing a breakpoint at the start of your loop and stepping through each line. You'll find it that way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB.NET 2008 Application crashing during Do Loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977390/vb-net-2008-application-crashing-during-do-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would encourage you to code with an Option Strict On declaration so as not to rely on implicit casting from one type to another.

The answer to your question is that you have declared an array of StudentHSC objects with (NumStudents + 1) elements. StudentHSC is a reference type and therefore each element of the array is a pointer to an object. Until an object is created on the heap by use of the New keyword, each pointer is not pointing to any object or is pointing to "Nothing". Therefore if you try to assign a value to a property of an element (e.g. StudentName), you will get a "null reference exception". To solve the problem, insert the following line at the top of the For loop:

```
student(count) = New StudentHSC
```

You haven't shown the StudentHSC class so I am assuming it has a constructor that takes no parameters.

So the start of the For loop should look like this:

```
For count = 0 To NumStudent
    student(count) = New StudentHSC
    student(count).StudentName = InputBox("Enter the student's name")
```

Also you have a lot of unused or redundant variables and you should be validating the user entries of the input boxes to ensure that numerical values have been provided.

EDIT:

The If clause should look like this:

```
If student(count).HscMark < 50 Then
    student(count).HscRank = 1
    HscBand(0) = HscBand(0) + 1
    lstStuData.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {student(count).StudentName, student(count).StudentScore.ToString, student(count).HscMark.ToString, student(count).HscRank.ToString}))
ElseIf student(count).HscMark >= 50 AndAlso student(count).HscMark < 60 Then
    student(count).HscRank = 2
    HscBand(1) = HscBand(1) + 1
    lstStuData.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {student(count).StudentName, student(count).StudentScore.ToString, student(count).HscMark.ToString, student(count).HscRank.ToString}))
ElseIf student(count).HscMark >= 60 AndAlso student(count).HscMark < 70 Then
    student(count).HscRank = 3
    HscBand(2) = HscBand(2) + 1
    lstStuData.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {student(count).StudentName, student(count).StudentScore.ToString, student(count).HscMark.ToString, student(count).HscRank.ToString}))
ElseIf student(count).HscMark >= 70 AndAlso student(count).HscMark < 80 Then
    student(count).HscRank = 4
    HscBand(3) = HscBand(3) + 1
    lstStuData.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {student(count).StudentName, student(count).StudentScore.ToString, student(count).HscMark.ToString, student(count).HscRank.ToString}))
ElseIf student(count).HscMark >= 80 AndAlso student(count).HscMark < 90 Then
    student(count).HscRank = 5
    HscBand(4) = HscBand(4) + 1
    lstStuData.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {student(count).StudentName, student(count).StudentScore.ToString, student(count).HscMark.ToString, student(count).HscRank.ToString}))
ElseIf student(count).HscMark >= 90 AndAlso student(count).HscMark <= 100 Then
    student(count).HscRank = 6
    HscBand(5) = HscBand(5) + 1
    lstStuData.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {student(count).StudentName, student(count).StudentScore.ToString, student(count).HscMark.ToString, student(count).HscRank.ToString}))
End If
```

Comment: I've edited the post, it now includes the structure and public variables.

Do i still include the code you included?

Comment: With the additional code, the picture is quite different. I had assumed that StudentHSC was declared as a "Class" and therefore a reference type but you have declared it as a "Structure" which makes it a value type. Therefore members of primitive data types such as Integer and String are initialised with default values and a call to "student(count) = New StudentHSC" is not required. Using a structure rather than a class, I am unable to precipitate an error. Can you clarify what is happening at your end?

Comment: Also HighestMark, LowestMark, ClassTotal, ClassMean and student are all unused variables. MaxScore is declared twice (once as a public Integer and once as a local Decimal). Band1 to Band 6 and the elements of the HscBand array are assigned values that are not used in any meaningful way.

Comment: At the very last increment of the loop the vbhost.exe or what ever it's called that loads the program when you're testing crashes, as in it doesn't respond and and stops working. This happens in the last increment.
Say i entered 5 students, it loops through, i enter the details and it shows up the 4 students details (name, score, etc). As i enter the last student name and score it doesn't show up on the viewlist but instead crashes. I assume this has something to do with the numstudent variables being numstudent - 1?

Comment: highestMark, class total, lowestmark, etc are used variables, they become used after the looping happens, since the crashing happens just before the loop ends i can't get the variables to show up in the list. My understanding of arrays is that if you entered 6 it becomes 7 because 0 is used to? So if i entered 5 students the count would go to 6, that's why i had NumStudent = NumStudent -1 so that it becomes the actual amount of students. Correct me if i am wrong here, I can't use

    For count = 1 to NumStudents

Because of the needed 0 ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with NumStudent. You have already decremented it by one to account for a zero-based array. I can't replicate your error. What exactly is the error message and on which line is it occurring?

Comment: I don't recommend you change the array numbering logic. The upper bound of the array should be the original value assigned to NumStudents minus one. If the upper bound of the array is 5, that array will have 6 elements - 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 & 5. So you want to iterate from 0 to 5 if if 6 is entered as the number of students.

Comment: Alright so i am getting no error messages at all. Listview won't add the last student details to the list and then the program crashes. I did the same thing for 2 students, the last student (in this case the 2nd) won't be added in and the program crashes.

Comment: OK I see the problem. I suspect that the crashing is occurring after the loop exits in code that you have not shown. The reason why students are not being added to the list view is because you are only testing for <50 and the exact values 50, 60, 70, 80 and 90. Students with any other score will not be added to the Listview. See my edit above.

Comment: It worked! I had already added in the >= for rest before your edit but i didn't replace the <101 to <=100

Thank you very much! Now i can see the rest of my program works fine... except for class median....

Comment: You need to add validation in case the user clicks on cancel on the input box or enters a non-numerical value. Also it is good practice to use "AndAlso" rather than "And" unless the right hand expression is the return value of a function that needs to be called. Using "And" above evaluates the right-hand expression even if the left-hand expression is False. This is unnecessary because the return value of the whole expression is going to be False if the left-hand expression is False so there is no need to evaluate the right-hand expression.